# How can I disable javascript for the page that's being opened?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was up till 1 am last night trying to find an example of how to do this. My theory is that I'd write a function that would comment out all javascript.

The second option would be to add the url to the list of javascript settings.

Right now my extension is very simple:

```
function linkOnClick(info, tab) {
    window.open(info.linkUrl)
}

chrome.contextMenus.create(
{title: "Load with no Javascript", contexts:["link"], onclick: linkOnClick});
```

This is my first extension and I'm kind of lost.

edit: let me know if I should also post the manifest.json.

Comment: Comment out all JavaScript where?  On a page the user is visiting?  Do you want to disable JavaScript?

Comment: Exactly. All I want it to do is disable javascript for the page it's opening. I'm trying to write an extension I really want, which I couldn't find in the chrome store. Everything seems to be working so far, except I'm clueless on how begin disabling the javascript on the link that's being loaded.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663359/google-chrome-extension-how-to-turn-javascript-on-off, https://github.com/maximelebreton/quick-javascript-switcher,  You should probably investigate the ContentSettings API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings

Comment: It looks like I might be using ContentSetting.clear() to do it. I'll post later to say if that's what it actually is or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: I can't mark this as solved for 2 days (why? who knows.), so I'll probably not remember to mark this as solved. So accept this as the official making: **SOLVED**.

chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set is the thing that disables javascript.

Here's the part that disables javascript. 
(Google, here's what an actual example should look like):

```
    chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set(
        {'primaryPattern':AnyDomainName, /*this is a string with the domain*/
        'setting': "block", /* block the domain. Can be switched to "allow" */
        'scope':'regular'}, /*it's either regular or incognito*/
        function(){ 
            /*optional action you want to 
            take place AFTER something's been blocked'*/    
            });
```

Here's the script I used to import into my json script for my chrome extension.

```
var link=""
var pattern=""

function linkOnClick(info, tab) {
    r = /:\/\/(.[^/]+)/;
    link=info.linkUrl
    pattern="http://"+link.match(r)[1]+"/*"

    chrome.contentSettings.javascript.set(
        {'primaryPattern':pattern,
        'setting': "block",
        'scope':'regular'},
        function(){

        window.open(link)

        });
    }

chrome.contextMenus.create({title: "Load with no Javascript", contexts:["link"], onclick: linkOnClick});
```

I couldn't tell how any of this worked by reading the developer.chrome.com page! They really need add complete working examples or allow a way for users to add examples. I can't even use it. The git hub link is what saved me.

Comment: Don't forget to _unset_ it.

Comment: You can't mark it as solved by your own answer, to give chance to others to contribute a better one. You should wait and do it - it will give you reputation points.

Comment: Other answers would be nice, but I don't think too many people are writing browser extensions, so I'd be surprised if someone else gave an answer. I'll add an unset. good idea