# Is it possible to disable javascript from within JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, and I want to be able to disable JavaScript based on a condition. So the page loads, a bunch of JavaScript runs, and if my condition is met then I'd like to disable all JavaScript. Is that possible? We would need to terminate/stop the currently running scripts.

I don't care too much if my chrome extension's script is stopped/disabled as well. But it would be nice if I could keep just that javascript running.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome extension - how to turn JavaScript on/off?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663359/google-chrome-extension-how-to-turn-javascript-on-off)

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to achieve this is by defining a object with all your functions in it and then deleting said object from memory like so.

```
var obj = {


    first : function(){

        return "1";


    },

    second : function(){

        return "2";


    }


};

console.log( obj.first() ); // "1"
console.log( obj.second() ); // "2"

delete obj; // will remove from memory thus disabling it.

//will now return error
console.log( obj.first() );
console.log( obj.second() );
```

Please note though if you declare a var outside the var obj scope that points to obj it will still exist even after using delete.

```
var obj = {


    first : function(){

        return "1";


    },

    second : function(){

        return "2";


    }


};

var stillAlive = obj;
delete obj; // will it remove from memory?

//Ha gotcha i'm still here.
console.log( stillAlive.first() );
console.log( stillAlive.second() );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering a bit more how I would do it without redefining a javascript, like if I could make a chrome extension disable the javascript with a toggle, or after a short wait.

Comment: The comment under your question is what you want then.